# I am an intern of/in/at [company name]?

Tags: word-choice, at-in, in-of

I want to say that I am doing my internship in/at [company name].

Please give me some more examples using the word "intern" or "internship".
There seem to be differences between e.g. hospital and business places.

Answer (score 3):

for company you need to use at:

I am doing my internship at Yale-New Haven Children's Hospital in New Haven

Currently, I am doing my internship at the International Institute of Administrative Sciences, in Brussels, for a period of 16 weeks.

I am doing my internship at ESA-ESTEC

I am doing my internship at Loblaw in Toronto

Comment: so it's the same that I should use "I am an intern at Yale-New Haven Children's Hospital in New Haven"?

Comment: @yidanwang yes. it's always "at" when you're talking about the company. you could be an intern *in* a specific division of the company.

Comment: When using a general description instead of a company name, you can just use "X intern," as in "I'm a hospital intern" or "I'm a marketing intern."

Comment: oh then I may be _in_ the R&D group since it's a small company...Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Nicole this is helpful. I remember seeing something like "medical intern" but it seems not the same case... also there are intern reporter, intern programmer, etc.

Comment: I suppose there is a slight difference in meaning. "Intern at X" describes where you work or who you work for, while "X intern" describes the type of work you do. For example, compare "I'm an intern at New Haven Children's Hospital" and "I'm a medical intern."

Comment: @Nicole yes I see. very clear explanation. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Merriam-Webster defines *[intern](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/intern)* simply as

> an advanced student or graduate usually in a professional field (as medicine or teaching) gaining supervised practical experience (as in a hospital or classroom)

In practice, however, the nature of work performed by interns and internships varies greatly from profession to profession and industry to industry. For example, in fields with very long training periods such as medicine or architecture, an *intern* is someone with relatively advanced education and responsibilities. In contrast, in general business and government environments, an intern may be an undergraduate or even a high schooler who is there simply to observe a professional work environment, and whose archetypal workday features mornings at the coffee maker and afternoons at the photocopier.

You can broadly compare *to intern* with *to study* or *to work*, as indeed it lies in between them, and use the same prepositions.

> I am an intern at ABC, Corp.
>
> I am an intern in database administration
>
> I am interning at ABC, Corp.
>
> I am interning in database administration.

Now, in the aforementioned fields where *intern* has a special meaning, you may need to provide additional information to avoid confusion. If you were to say

> I am an intern at Memorial Hospital

it would be reasonable for an American listener to assume you are a medical doctor in your [first year of residency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internship_(medicine)). If, in fact, you are working in the accounting department, you would need to add the context:

> I am an intern in the accounting department at Memorial Hospital
>
> I am interning in the accounting department at Memorial Hospital
>
> I am an accounting intern at Memorial Hospital
>
> I have an internship in the accounting department at Memorial Hospital

Comment: Thanks for the cultural background! and also make me realize that intern is also a verb. Intuitively I would go like "I am an intern accountant (always intern goes before a job title like an adjective...) at Memorial Hospital"...but it returns much less results than _accounting intern_ in google...

Comment: by the way, should I say "much less results" or "much fewer results"?

Answer (score 0):

Here are some examples:

1. I'm an intern for the cardiologist department at Cedar Sinai Hospital.
2. I currently have internship with Microsoft as a software support.
3. I'm doing my internship at UCLA.

Comment: oh I googled the differences of "work for/at/with", and "at UCLA" is probably like _at_ college. (too much focused on the specific words earlier...) thanks for the examples!